# WHERE in Aggregate function

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, where-clause, having

I have a quick question. I know that we cannot use `WHERE` clause in an aggregate function in  MySQL. The table structure is as follows:

```
+----+------+----------+--------+
| ID | Name | Location | Active |
+----+------+----------+--------+
|  1 | Aaaa | India    | 0      |
|  2 | Aaaa | USA      | 0      |
|  3 | Aaaa | USA      | 1      |
|  4 | Aaaa | India    | 0      |
|  5 | Aaaa | UK       | 0      |
|  6 | Aaaa | India    | 1      |
|  7 | Aaaa | USA      | 1      |
|  8 | Aaaa | USA      | 0      |
|  9 | Aaaa | India    | 0      |
| 10 | Aaaa | UK       | 1      |
+----+------+----------+--------+
```

The query I have here is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `location`, `active` FROM `users` GROUP BY `location`;
```

The above query will give me the counts of the location. But, I need only the active users. So, I need a `WHERE` clause that does something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `location`, `active` FROM `users` GROUP BY `location` WHERE `active`=1;
```

The above query is invalid. The valid query would be using `HAVING`. But, if I change the query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `location`, `active` FROM `users` GROUP BY `location` HAVING `active`=1;
```

The counts are no different from the original query, which is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `location`, `active` FROM `users` GROUP BY `location`;
```

So, what am I supposed to do for getting the user counts of the location, who are active? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“The above query is invalid”_ – but only because you messed up the order of WHERE and GROUP BY, I suppose … _“The valid query would be using HAVING”_ – nope, that would _mean_ something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use where before group by so where clause will filter out the results according to your criteria and you can have your count on basis of your where criteria

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `location`, `active` 
FROM `users` 
 WHERE `active`=1
GROUP BY `location`
```

In addition to your specific question you can also use sum with your criteria so this will return as boolean and you can have your count on basis of your expression like

```
SELECT sum(`active`=1), `location`, `active` 
FROM `users` 
GROUP BY `location`
```

Above sum expression is equivalent to `sum(CASE when active=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar [*`Fiddle Demo`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/527dd/2) for better understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `WHERE` before the `GROUP BY` if you want to filter rows before aggregating. I you want to do some calculation among rows already aggregated, you have to use a `CASE` expression inside the aggregate. I don't think that's what you're doing here, so just put the `WHERE` clause in the right place.

The query looks like this, with `active` removed because it's now redundant (will always be 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), location
  FROM users
 WHERE active = 1
 GROUP BY location, active
```

It's important here to be reminded of the logical order of operations of an SQL query:

1. FROM: starting table, view, derived table
2. JOIN: adding additional tables, views, etc.
3. WHERE: filtering the rows from the initial table and joined tables
4. GROUP BY: aggregating the rows that have been filtered by WHERE
5. HAVING: filtering the aggregated rows output by GROUP BY
6. SELECT: pick columns and compute expressions
7. ORDER BY: sort the resulting rows, with selected columns and computed expressions available for ordering
8. LIMIT: control which and how many rows go back to the client

If you keep this in mind, it'll be easier to understand when to do certain types of filtering and what the rows that you're filtering look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where in aggregate queries, however, it must be before group by and after from